# GAE Logging disappeared? How to restore?

Tags: google-app-engine

Here's how I used to enable logging:

- Log into Google Developers Console
- From the dropdown at the top, choose the project to monitor.
- From the side bar, choose Monitoring, then Logs

I can't find that feature any more. Now apparently I need to go into Google Cloud Monitoring and then... what? I tried creating a dashboard, but couldn't seem to find anything that just showed the event log.

An RTFM would be welcomed if accompanied by a link. I have tried searching. I'd think that https://app.google.stackdriver.com/event-log would have the event log but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: it still there, i am using it daily on 3 versions of the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no longer an item under `Monitoring`, it's at the same level with `Monitoring` (just a few lines below):

[image]

You can 'pin' it in the side-bar and then you'll find it faster on the top bar (once you get used with the new icon):

[image]

**April 13, 2016 Update:** The section under which the Logging menu exists is now called `STACKDRIVER`, not `OPERATIONS`:

[image]