# Where are the deployment parameters and credentials stored?

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I am trying out the tutorial at https://console.cloud.google.com/start/appengine?project=xxxxx.

I am able to launch the app on my machine and browse it at port 8080. However when I click `Deploy` in the GAE Launcher, the app is deployed to localhost:8080 instead of to Google.

How do I deploy to Google's server?

---

My developer console is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Is there a deployment log available?  Did you also try http://<your_app_name>. appspot. com? (your local server may continue running after the deployment, potentially suggesting that the deployment was done on localhost).  Or rather: how did you conclude that the deployment was on localhost?

Comment: Yes, I tried the appspot.com url but it says `The requested URL / was not found on this server`.  After clicking Deploy the browser launched to localhost:8080, preceded by a redirection for authentication to accounts.google.com. Log begins with: 2015-12-28 04:04:55 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--oauth2_credential_file=C:\\Users\\xxxx/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens', 'update', 'D:\\Documents\\Google Cloud\\appengine-flask-skeleton-master']" and no errors were reported.

Comment: Deployment was likely OK. You could check in the developer console info about the application,  in particular the logs -  I suspect there are issues with the app and you'll see a log for your request,  if so you'll have to debug your app code/config.

Comment: I don't think it was deployed to Google. I launched the cloud-shell and the folder was empty (other than profile files). Where is the log in the console? I see only Activity on the left, and clicking it shows `There's no activity yet.`

Comment: see this q&a: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235653/gae-logging-disappeared-how-to-restore/34236438#34236438

Comment: Thanks, but my developer console doesn't look like the one in that post. I have added a snapshot to my original question.

Comment: You have to create an application in Google Developers console and copy the Project id and paste it inside the file named appengine-web.xml, Within <application>Your Project</application> id and Deploy to GAE

Comment: That menu appears when you click on the 3 horizontal bars right above the Home menu

Comment: Log was empty.  Instead of the GAE Launcher, I deployed manually using the instruction on the console url: `appcfg.py -A glowing-net-763 update app.yaml` and also the one in the README.md: `appcfg.py -A glowing-net-763 --oauth2 update .`  Both gave a HTTP 403 error: You do not have permission to modify this app (app_id=u's~glowing-new-763').

Comment: There is an extra `~s` prepended to the app_id in the error message.  Is this of significance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause.

The credentials are stored in the file `C:\Users\xxx\.appcfg_oauth2_tokens`.

When I did the first deployment attempt, the default browser was already logged into a Google account different from the one that created the app in the Google's developer console, and I absent-mindedly authorized it.  As a result, the tokens file contains the wrong credentials.

By deleting the tokens file, I was prompted to log in again and could deploy properly.